Image overlay does not fit the MapContainer
Trying out react-leaflet I am not able to fit the custom map image into the MapContainer:
import { LatLngBoundsExpression } from 'leaflet';
import L from 'leaflet';
import { MapContainer, ImageOverlay, Marker } from 'react-leaflet';

interface ILeafletMap {
  geoLocation: { lat: number; lng: number };
}
const LeafLetMap = ({ geoLocation }: ILeafletMap) => {
  const bounds: LatLngBoundsExpression = [
    [4000, 200],
    [0, 0],
  ];

  return (
    <div className='h-full w-full border border-black'>
      <MapContainer
        className='h-full w-full border border-red-500'
        attributionControl={false}
        center={[0, 0]}
        zoom={1}
        zoomControl={false}
        scrollWheelZoom={false}
        dragging={false}>
        <ImageOverlay
          className='h-full w-full'
          url='/images/content/leafletMap.png'
          bounds={bounds}
        />
      </MapContainer>
    </div>
  );
};

export default LeafLetMap;

This is a result I get so far.

I just don't get why image does not fit inside the MapContainer but goes way of the bounds.
I tried playing with bounds value, but I guess I just don't understand it. I am able to position it on x axis, but y axis is just stuck at one point and it won't move the image beyond that.
What I'm looking for is to just use this custom map image and be able to render provided marker on it.
